# Bootstrap date picker issue with angular mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap date picker & Angular.

I have a dropdown menu/form on mouse hover only. The drop down menu contains bootstrap date picker.  The problem is when user hover over date picker calendar, the underlying menu disappear.

The desired behavior would be to keep showing the calendar and underlying menu till user move mouse out of both the objects

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.formMenu = false;
    $('#dateInput').datepicker({
       format: "dd MM yyyy",
       
       autoclose: true,
       todayHighlight: true
   });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    
    
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div  ng-mouseover="formMenu=true" ng-mouseleave="formMenu=false">
        Dropdown
      </div>
      <div ng-show="formMenu" ng-mouseover="formMenu=true" ng-mouseleave="formMenu=false">
        <label>This should not disappear on calendar hover</label>
        
        <input type="text" class="date-picker date-filter text-left" id="dateInput">
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/CvQSWLGntsbVIoJASgqy?p=preview

Please suggest method to achieve the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not to sure that I have understood the question to 100 percent, but the calender opens onclick so you can set a property to true if you click into the input and set it to false on blur.

Something like this should work.

```
div ng-show="formMenu || datepickerHover" ng-mouseover="formMenu=true" ng-mouseleave="formMenu=false">
    <label>This should not disappear on calendar hover</label>

    <input type="text" class="date-picker date-filter text-left" id="dateInput" ng-click="datepickerHover = true" ng-blur="datepickerHover = false">
  </div>
```

I know it's more like a hack. To observe the DOM if a div with the class datepicker appears would also be an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your CSS looks something like this

```
.nav:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

So add the same to the menu itself

```
.menu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

That way, when you stop hovering on the nav, you'll still be doing something that allows the menu to be visible.